# Lubuntu can't unlock

Tags: lubuntu, password, lightdm, lock-screen

I am testing Lubuntu 16.04.3 as I want a lightweight UI on a machine that will mostly be used as a server. I want the screen to lock if a user walks away, so that if someone forgets to lock the computer, someone who is not authorized can not get on and start using it.

The problem I am having is that once locked (set the screen to go blank and lock after 10mins), the screen won't unlock. If the correct password is entered, it blacks out for a second and then just goes back to the username and password prompt that I just went though. If I put the wrong password in, it does as it should and has a red box with the alert that it was an incorrect password. It always logs in with the password fine, its only after a lock.

When light locker is turned off it doesn't lock so no password is needed and it is fine. So has anyone installed Lubuntu 16.04.3, locked it (it does the same thing from the lock option as the time-out) and tried unlocking it? I am using this on a virtualbox, so that may cause some issues?

UPDATE: Just did a fresh install of Lubuntu 16.04.3 in VirtualBox 5.1.26 and as soon as I log in, clicked to lock the screen (from the lower right menu) and it would not unlock again.

Comment: Voted it up as I have the same issue.

Comment: This guy somehow figured out to press Ctr-Alt-F1. It works for me.
[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975703/ubuntu-17-10-with-lxde-locking-leads-to-black-blank-screen)