# Ubuntu 17.10 with LXDE locking leads to black/blank screen

Tags: 17.10, lock-screen, lxde, lock

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10. As my laptop is rather on the weak side (performance wise), I grew quite uncomfortable with the new desktop as everything seemed to take longer, the laptop being slower overall.

So, I installed LXDE, lubuntu-session packages, etc., to make a transition to the more lightweight LX desktop environment. I am super happy about it, as the system now feels super fast and responsive.

One issue remains: If my session gets locked (by timeout, laptop lid close, or manual lock) I end up with a black and empty screen. Not even a mouse pointer, not responding to any clicks or simple key presses. The only remedy I found was killing/rebooting the entire machine. 
After some playing around, I found that Ctrl+Alt+F1 takes me back to the login screen.

I tried to google for this problem, but didn't find any help: Several similar problems were discussed, like having no login screen right after boot (which is not my problem), of another solution talking about "Light Locker Settings" and turning off/on some stuff - but I don't seem to have this menu...

I do not really understand what's going on, and why I seem to end up at the wrong Ctrl-Alt-F* interface.

For me it's only a thing of minor to medium importance, as I found a way to work around it. But, of course, I would be glad if someone could point me to a clean solution.

(A solution is great, but if you could elaborate your answer a bit, I would be very grateful, as I'd really like to learn more about the inner workings of my system.)

Comment: I am having the same issue on Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score -1):

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 to go to a virtual terminal, and log in. Issue this command:

> ps ax | grep lock

If you see light-locker running, kill it

> killall light-locker

Return to your gui by pressing Ctrl-Alt-F7. Hopefully it is unlocked now.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the issue, it's only a workaround. (And one might as well just go to a console (Altc-Ctrl-F1), then go back to light-locker (Ctrl-Alt-F8) and just enter the password.

Comment: True, I never found a solution. I finally "fixed" it by disabling light-locker and installing xscreensaver.